# I want to pass data on button click to the next page and when redirect to it using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a ticket order service website on WordPress. All orders are created as custom post types. On `archive-order.php` page are queried all available orders. On `single-order.php` is order form.  The user chooses what particular service, he/she want to order on the archive-order page, and then is redirected to the single-order page to fill the form. Price depends on `/order/$custom-post-type-name/` URL.

I want to add an intermediate page between archive and single for order confirmation. What's the best way to achieve this?

I believe, that I need to pass href attr equal to `/order/$custom-post-type-name/` from the archive to confirmation link's href on the new page.

I tried to use ajax, but I get 404 error or after the button click, nothing is happening. Maybe there is a problem, that I test everything on my local xampp server.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn">
    <a class="anim300 isigyti double"
       href="<?php echo get_permalink($paray->ID);?>"
    >
        <?php _e("Order", "test");?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.btn a.isigyti').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'confirmation.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            service: name
        }
    }); 
});
```

On confirmation page:

```
<?php           
session_start();            
$_SESSION['service'] = $_POST['service'];       
?>

<div class="full left">
<a class="anim300 isigyti begrup isitest2" href="<?php $_POST['service']; ?>">
<?php _e("Continue", "test");?></a>
</div>
```

I can't get redirect to work on btn click. What am I missing? Also maybe where is a better way to create a confirmation page in my case.

Comment: "I get 404 error "  Then you're not providing the correct path to your file in the ajax call.  We can't really tell you what the path should be, because we don't know your system.  View the request details in your browser's network inspector to see what is being used, and make sure it is what you expect it to be.  Also, you don't have any response handler on your ajax call.  How do you expect anything to be done with the response?  ajax is not a redirect, it makes a request and gets a response.  It is then up to _you_ to tell it what to do with the response.

Comment: If you are on the page with the URL `/order/$custom-post-type-name/`, then making a request to `confirmation.php` of course means, you are making it to `/order/$custom-post-type-name/confirmation.php` effectively - and it is probably rather doubtful that actually exists.

Comment: I'm making request when I'm on `archive-order.php` page. I missed the trick about response handler. I will read about it and test everything more.